# Remove text except for a later exception before a certain character,

Tags: notepad++

So i have this list of items, and i need to filter out certain parts cause of the output used by a program. Example :
Start (what it looks like currently) :

word1:word2:word3

all "words" have different sizes in text. i need it to look like :

word2:word3

Thanks in advance for any answers. 
(first answer did not work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove text before a certain string in every line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995719/remove-text-before-a-certain-string-in-every-line)

Answer (score 0):

Use replace with regular expression:

```
^[^:]*:\s*
```

This will match anything before first colon, including colon, and any potential space (if none also ok) after the first colon. Replace that with empty string.