# Remove text before a certain string in every line

Tags: notepad++

So i have this list of items, and i need to filter out certain parts cause of the output used by a program. Example : Start (what it looks like currently) :

word1:word2:word3

all "words" have different sizes in text. i need it to look like :

word2:word3

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove text except for a later exception before a certain character,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994016/remove-text-except-for-a-later-exception-before-a-certain-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the first column from your `:` separated rows:

1. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>
2. tick "Regular expression" in "Search Mode"
3. Find what: `^[^:]+:(.+)$`
4. Replace with: `$1`
5. Click "Replace" or "Replace All"

Comment: Works, but i need to do it on 1100+ lines, when i press replace all it gets rid of everything cause its doing it over and over, fix?

Comment: @Interlacing - sorry my bad, n++ doesn't jump to the next line after a match but continues from where the cursor is. Updated my answer to force it to move on to the next line.

Comment: you sir are a legend!